# Mergelyan's theorem from Runge's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

From Conway, A course in functional analysis, page 85. Corollary 8.5.

I want to ask for a hint how to deduce Mergelyan's theorem from Runge's theorem, assuming a functional analysis rhetoric proof. This is listed as a corollary after Runge's theorem with no proof given. I thought about it, but I cannot remove the key construction of a measure $$\overline{\mu}(w)=\int_{K}\frac{d|\mu|(z)}{|z-w|}$$ in the book, because later one need a variation of Cauchy's intergral formula to prove that if $\int gd\mu=0$ for each $g$ in the closure in $C(K)$ of rational functionals with poles in $E$, then $\int fd\mu=0$ for any $f$ analytic on an open set containing $K$. In order to show that in a certain step (8.3) one need to prove that $$(\frac{d}{dw})^{n}\overline{\mu}(w_{0})=0$$for any $n$, hence $\overline{\mu}(w_{0})$ must be $0$. This relies on the assumption $g$ is a rational function.

The key assumption in Mergelyan's theorem is $\mathbb{C}-K$ is connected. Therefore I need to use the assumption somehow. It is not correct that every meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}-K$ must be analytic. So if I do not modify the author's proof significantly, I do not know how to prove Mergelyan's theorem based on his work. I feel I must be thinking in the wrong way somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overthinking this. Let me quote Runge's theorem from the book:

> **8.1. Runge's theorem.** Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb C$ and let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb C_\infty\setminus K$ that meets each component of $\mathbb C_\infty\setminus K$. If $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $K$, then there are rational functions $f_n$ whose only poles lie in $E$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly in $K$.

(Here $\mathbb C_\infty$ is the extended complex plane.)

If   $\mathbb C \setminus K$ is connected, you can choose $E=\{\infty\}$, thus forcing all $f_n$ to be polynomials.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.